# C# Setup Project taskbar search icon is set to default while all other icon are displaying correctly

Tags: c#, search, installation, icons, searchbar

I created a little project, a setup for the project, and gave the project an icon (from the Application settings in the project properties). Furthermore, I have my setup creating a desktop shortcut and programs menu shortcut. Both shortcuts have the project's icon (selected from the Icon property, chosen by selecting the project, which is the primary output).

Basically everything works perfectly. In all locations the shortcuts and .exe file have the chosen icon, EXCEPT when I search for it from the taskbar.

[Search Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ1tI.png)

After looking into both of those locations, the bottom one (correct one) is the search result from the desktop shortcut.

The top one (the problem) is located in the start menu programs folder. What I don't understand is that the shortcut in that folder has the correct icon. So the only problem is the search result. Is there any way to change the search result's icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a work around. Deleted my Setup Project and created an identical one. The first one was more of a learning process, so my only explanation is that perhaps I created the problem without knowing it.

If you have this weird issue, just recreate your Setup Project!